# Do objects also have some scope like methods local variables have?

Tags: c#-2.0

i have a confusion how gabage collector decides that an object is no more in use, do object have some scope?

like if i have code

```
class A { in x; m1(){}}
class B {A a=new a(); a.x=10; }
```

so i want to know that when the object become unusable

i mean in the above code if class be reaches to end line then when it exit that class do object a can go for garbage collection, and after that A class varibale will agian hold is default value of will permanently value 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects do have scope as any other variable and as defined by language rules.

An object is garbage collected when there are no other objects referencing it.

GC has its more or less complex algorithm for determining that . One of them is reference counting.

When a local variabla goes out of scope it looses a reference, if refernece coutn is 0 then is garbage collected.

Garbage collection is not deterministic, that is you can't decide eactly when to garbage collect it.

Setting a variable to null will basically make the variable garbage collectable.

Comment: but how it is decided that object is no mre referenced or every object after use i should explicitly use obj=null.  or it happens automatically, how Gc decide an object is no more referenced

Comment: no thats ok that GC in non deterministic in nature that when it will garbage collect the object but can we know that now this object is gone for GC

Comment: Yes , you can know when the object is subject to garbage collection in the situations I posted above, when it goes out of scope o when you explicitly set it to null. The aexact scoping rules of the C# language can be googled.

Comment: but in our code we never explicitly use obj=null then how an object looses reference and become eligible for GC

Answer (score 2):

Only declarations (type, member, local) have scope. Nothing else.

Comment: so we can never predict that when object will be use less and again holding its default values

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: That's the GC's job.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collectors work by finding and tagging all objects that are reachable from known starting points (e.g., each thread's stack, all static variables, ...), and then blowing away objects that didn't get tagged. The full explanation is usually far more complex, but this is the essence of it.

Comment: if i on some point in class B i again create object like A a=new a(); then is it mean that there are two object in the memory who are sharing the all methods and having the separate copy of instance variables.. or a second object will be created and "a" will be referring to that the first object will be gone for GC